# adding view with delay

Tags: android, view, handler

I am trying to add delay while adding view to mainview but views spear simultaneously. Please help.

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
    final HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(TestViewActivity.this);
    final LinearLayout lhsv = new LinearLayout(TestViewActivity.this);

    final Animation a1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.00f, 1.00f);
    a1.setDuration(350);
    a1.setFillAfter(true);  
    for(int k =0; k < 5; k++){
         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //write your code here...
                    TextView tv = new TextView(TestViewActivity.this);  
                    tv.setText("Text");
                    tv.setTextSize(42);
                    tv.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
                    tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    tv.clearAnimation();   
                    tv.startAnimation(a1);
                    lhsv.addView(tv, temp);
                    temp++;
                }
            }, 2000);
        }

    hsv.addView(lhsv);
    ll.addView(hsv);
```

temp is static int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to your code, result may be adding all views simultaneously after 2second, right?
the delay time must be changed by int k like below.

```
for(int k =0; k < 5; k++){
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //write your code here...
                TextView tv = new TextView(TestViewActivity.this);  
                tv.setText("Text");
                tv.setTextSize(42);
                tv.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
                tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tv.clearAnimation();   
                tv.startAnimation(a1);
                lhsv.addView(tv, temp);
                temp++;
            }
        }, 2000 + 2000 * k);
    }
```

and I recommend to don't make handler which is not necessary. just post runnables to one handler.

Comment: Thanks it works....but there is a flicking issue and secondly can you plz provide the example of post runnables to one handler.

Comment: final Handler handler = new Handler(); according to this code, you already constructed a handler. just post runnable to this handler. like this, handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ ...}

Comment: Can you plz guide me about flickering issue, for example previous textview also disappear and come back why :(

Comment: If you add a view to a ViewGroup, the ViewGroup will layout again, and draw again also. when drawing again we can see flickering. try adding views on the creation with visible attribute set gone. and post runnable which setting visibility to visible and start animation.